# IDatabaseCompact.Compact() on an used IWorkspace

Tags: vb.net, workspace, arcmap, arcobjects, compact-database

I am writting an ArcMap-AddIn with vb.net. I got an error when trying to `compact` my IWorkspace(mdb), the error is:

> COMException
>
> You tried to open a database, which was already opened by the user
>   'ADMIN' on Computer 'XXXXXX'. Try it again when the database is
>   available.
>
> On ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IDatabaseCompact.Compact() on
>   MyProject.MyClass.CompactGDB(IWorkspace pWS)

How can i compact the used workspace?
There are 8 other functions which also used my workspace.

Any suggestions?

The Code:

```
' CompactGDB
    Public Sub CompactGDB(ByVal pWS As IWorkspace)

        Dim pDatabaseCompact As IDatabaseCompact
        If (TypeOf pWS Is IDatabaseCompact) Then
            pDatabaseCompact = CType(pWS, IDatabaseCompact)
            If (pDatabaseCompact.CanCompact) Then
                Try
                    pDatabaseCompact.Compact()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.type & ex.Message & ex.StackTrace, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                End Try    
            End If
        End If    
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

Before calling the Compact() method make sure there are not **any existing locks** on the database.

If it is a **file geodatabase** then open the **gdb** directory in Windows Explorer and look for **LOCK** type files, they end in .lock.

For **personal geodatabase** there will be a **.ldb** file in the directory with the same name as the **.mdb**.

- If you have a layer or table from the geodatabase loaded in the map
  then you will not be able to remove all locks.
- If another user is
  accessing the geodatabase then you will not be able to remove all
  locks.
- If you are using arcobjects to temporarily access the
  geodatabase then you need to use good practices and close any
  geodatabase resources when the calling process ends.  *This includes
  releasing all COM objects when you are finished with them.*

Use the **[ComReleaser Class](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Overview/000500000004000000/)** in **ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Connection.Local** namespace